# What is the difference between a spring and bolt action airsoft sniper

Tags: terminology, airsoft

What is the difference between a bolt action airsoft sniper and spring airsoft sniper. Which is easier to use and which is better.

Answer (score 3):

Bolt action only describes the act of rechambering a new round, and in the case of airsoft, either cocking the spring or readying the gas release machanism.

Spring sniper rifle describes what the power source is for the weapon in question.

E.G:

> Bolt action spring sniper rifle: A weapon powered by a spring, requiring recocking after each round fired through cycle of the bolt.
>
> Bolt action co2 rifle: Powered by co2, cycling the bolt loads a new bb and sets the mechanism.

On the topic of "which is better", I can only present the pros and cons of the systems I described. The spring system is incredibly reliable and consistent, but the bolt can be pretty heavy if a very stiff spring is used. The co2 system gets rid of the need for heavy force used to cock a spring, so higher velocities can be achived without having to strain yourself. But the downsides are less consistent preformance and lower reliability, since leaks is a possibility.

Hope this cleared things up, if you have more questions on airsoft in general, don't be afraid to PM me.

//Marcus

Comment: Also, CO2 weapons use consumables so the functioning costs are higher. Plus, gas performance can vary depending on the temperature (I have heard that some gases have a hard time in cold weather).